# SQL Server Convert a number

Tags: sql-server, casting

I have this number: 5.42418E+15
How do I convert this number to a 16 digit number like this:
4383452049412480?

I am doing it manually in excel by formatting that column to Number then I select 1234 format but I want this to be done in Sql server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @F as float(53)
set @F = 6713073544159400

select @F
      6.7130735441594E+15

select cast( @F as decimal)
      6713073544159400
```

Comment: This is not working (wrong answer), let me give you an example: 6.71307E+15 is 6713073544159400

Comment: @dijaijijfs - Try `declare @F24 as float(24) = 6.71307E+15, @F53 as float(53) = 6.71307E+15; select @F24, Cast( @F24 as decimal(38,0) ), @F53, Cast( @F53 as decimal(38,0) );`. The data types are critical to having the correct precision.

Comment: @dijaijijfs Yes my original didn't have the detail of the real number.  I changed my example to include more precision.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 CAST ( expression AS data_type [ ( length ) ] )
```